# Wordpress query_posts for Multiple variable not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to get results of the posts which has `category` and my custom taxonomy `Type` . I am trying this

```
$args = 'category=' . $cat . '&Type='.$type.'&order=ASC';
  query_posts($args);
```

I am receiving `$cat` and `$type` from a GET request. The problem is it is pulling up all the posts that belong to the `Type` taxonomy ireespective to `category`

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Please don't use `query_posts()` for fetching posts. For general post queries, use [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts).

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array($cat),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( $type ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

instead using `query_posts()`

Thank you!

Comment: Just For information... Don't use `query_posts`, why? 
[click here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Comment: Thank you So much for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
  $args = 'cat=' . $cat . '&post_type='.$type.'&order=ASC';
  query_posts($args);
```

for more reference: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts